# How to reimport model in Xcode from SAP system

Tags: ios, exception, model-view-controller, ios7, xcode5

I want to add a column to my table. This column has already been added in the backend Database which is SAP system. I can also see that value being populated in the extract when first connected to the SAP system. After successful login, it runs the material extract function module and returns a column "Price" which I need to add to my application in xcode.

Please help me.

Error: 
" terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: itemPrice)'
 First throw call stack:

```
    if(!found){
            NSMutableDictionary *mDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [mDic setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"itemId"] forKey:@"itemId"];
            [mDic setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"itemR"] forKey:@"itemR"];
            [mDic setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"itemQty"] forKey:@"itemQty"];
            [mDic setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"itemDesc"] forKey:@"itemDesc"];
            [mDic setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"itemPack"] forKey:@"itemPack"];
            [mDic setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"itemUOM"] forKey:@"itemUOM"];
            [mDic setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"itemNACS"] forKey:@"itemNACS"];
            [mDic setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"itemPrice"] forKey:@"itemPrice"];  // This is where the error is occuring.
            int qty = [[dic valueForKey:@"itemQty"] intValue];
           // float price = [[dic valueForKey:@"itemPrice"] floatValue];
           // price = price * qty;
           // [mDic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", price]  forKey:@"itemPrice"];

            mQty = qty;

            [mDic setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"itemLastSold"] forKey:@"itemLastSold"];
            [items addObject:mDic];
            [mDic release];
        }

Its actually not being retrieved from dic dictionary variable.

This is the code for adding that itemPrice to the table
 int mQty;
    //DELETE AND RE-ADD
    for (int i=0; i<[items count]; i++) {
        if([[dic valueForKey:@"itemId"] isEqualToString:[[items objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"itemId"]]){
            NSLog(@"qty %@",[dic valueForKey:@"itemQty"]);
            int qty = [[dic valueForKey:@"itemQty"] intValue];

            qty = qty + [[[items objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"itemQty"] intValue];
            NSDictionary *d =  [items objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog([d description]);

            [[items objectAtIndex:i] setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", qty] forKey:@"itemQty"];
found = YES;
[items removeObjectAtIndex:i];
 NSMutableDictionary *mDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [mDic setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"itemId"] forKey:@"itemId"];
            [mDic setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"itemR"] forKey:@"itemR"];
            [mDic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", qty] forKey:@"itemQty"];
            [mDic setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"itemDesc"] forKey:@"itemDesc"];
            [mDic setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"itemPack"] forKey:@"itemPack"];
            [mDic setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"itemUOM"] forKey:@"itemUOM"];
            [mDic setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"itemNACS"] forKey:@"itemNACS"];
            [mDic setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"itemPrice"] forKey:@"itemPrice"];  //added price column
 mQty = qty;
            [mDic setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"itemLastSold"] forKey:@"itemLastSold"];
//            [items insertObject:mDic atIndex:0];
            [items addObject:mDic];
            [mDic release];

            break;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that is causing the crash?

Comment: Looks like you're passing a nil object to a property that cannot be nil - but without code, there's not much anybody can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put nil into a NSMutableDictionary. If it's possible for dic to not have this key, you'll need to do something like this to prevent the crash:

```
if ([dic valueForKey:@"itemPrice"] != nil) {
    [mDic setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"itemPrice"] forKey:@"itemPrice"];
}
```

Or, you'll need to investigate why dic does not contain the itemPrice key.

Comment: That was very helpful. But how can I add this value to dic dictionary table. Sample code for retrieving other columns,
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"OrderItems" inManagedObjectContext:*context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorPageTemplateName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"itemDesc" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptorPageTemplateName, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sortDescriptorPageTemplateName release];

Comment: Add the code to your question and I'll see if I can help. My guess is that there's no itemPrice attribute in your Core Data entity. You'll need to add that attribute, and whatever code populates the entity will need to be updated to populate itemPrice.

Comment: You need to look at the core data entity for whatever entity this is. You can't just setObject:forKey: with an arbitrary key name; the key needs to exist in the entity.

Comment: Yes Greg, Actually the values need to be retrieved from XML generated from data source. I have finally fixed it. Thank you very much for your help.